# Is there any way or javascript function that can be written to scroll scrollbars that are part of an element eg: table/div

Tags: java, selenium, scrollbar

In my application there has 2 scroll bar .one is web page scroll bar and another one is inner table scroll bar.
My task is only to scroll down table scroll bar.So for that I used JavaScript

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.id("table id"));
((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("argument[0].scrollIntoView(true);", element);
```

My test cases are getting passed but scroll bar doesn't move down of table. So please anyone can help me would be more appreciatable.
Thanks,
I am looking solution of inner scroll scroll down and up.

Answer (score 0):

You're probably trying to scroll an already visible element and that's why it's not scrolling. So first, try giving an element in the table that isn't visible, something like:

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.id("table id"));
WebElement lastTableElement = element.findElement(By.cssSelector("tr:last-child"));
((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("argument[0].scrollIntoView(true);", element);
```

And for scrolling up to the first child again:

```
    WebElement lastTableElement = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("tr:first-child"));
```

You can also do scrolling by pixels:

```
((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("argument[0].scrollTop += 100;", element);
```

Comment: Thanks for reply but still it's not working.My Testcase is going to pass but table scrolling is not working.

Comment: Please check this webpage. there has 2 tables having scroll bar ,now i want to scroll down first table. [webpage](http://www.cssplay.co.uk/menu/tablescroll.html) . **Data comes dynamically (No any element which i can use to search and scroll down perform automatically.**

Comment: I made a mistake in the second code line. Try my updated code.